# Apache Sqoop/Pig field escaping

Tags: java, apache-pig, sqoop

We are exporting some data from MySQL using Sqoop, doing some processing with it via Apache Pig, and then attempting to export that data from HDFS back into a MySQL database. However, when exporting the data, we are running into issues:

```
java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".proseries.com"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:554)
    at mdm_urls.__loadFromFields(mdm_urls.java:419)
```

The HDFS data looks like (tab separated):

```
id:int  url:text  tld:text  port:int
```

Somehow the `tld` field is being imported into the `port` column *for some rows*. Out of ~250M rows, this is only the case for less than 10. My initial assumption was that the url field must have a tab in it. However, we have stripped all tabs in our Pig script:

```
REGISTER target/mystuff.jar;

legacy_urls = LOAD 'url' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id, sha1, url_text);
legacy_urls_norm = FOREACH legacy_urls GENERATE id AS id, sha1 AS sha1, REPLACE(REPLACE(url_text, '\n', ''), '\t', '') AS url_text;

urls = FOREACH legacy_urls_norm GENERATE id, url_text, mystuff.RootDomain(url_text), mystuff.Protocol(url_text), mystuff.Host(url_text), mystuff.Path(url_text), mystuff.EffectiveTld(url_text), mystuff.Port(url_text), sha1;

STORE urls INTO 'mdm_urls';
```

Here is my sqoop export command:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://hostnmae/db_name --input-fields-terminated-by "\t" --table test --export-dir my_urls
```

I am having a difficult time debugging this because the sqoop errors do not give any indication as to what row it was working on (so that I can confirm if a tab char is still present, etc). My first question is, how might I better troubleshoot this issue? My second question is, how are people escaping bad input data with PIG?

Comment: Can you show more of your script? Usually, if a field's data doesn't match the declared type, you won't get an error, just a `FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED` warning.

Comment: Sure, full script has been added to the main description.

Comment: Could you also share the map task log generated by Sqoop as the exception is suggesting?

Comment: it looks like the field with value '.proseries.com' goes into a numeric column. Could it be something like autogenerated ID column of your table?

Comment: After taking a look a closer look at the map task logs, I discovered the issue was on the original import of the data to HDFS. There are tabs in the raw data and when PIG goes to read it, the data is already skewed by one or more fields. I have not been able to figure out if PIG allows for fields to be escaped. So far we have been taking care to clean the data before importing it to HDFS via sqoop.